# Where is an official code for the European Union defined?

Tags: taxonomy, iso, country-codes

There is no code for the European Union in ISO 3166 or UN.M49. CLDR states that its own list does not contain a code for the European Union. I've seen the code "EU" used, but I can't find any official list that contains it. Is it in any official list of codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not in a list *per se*, but the code `EU` was officially "reserved" by the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency to represent the European Union. This is discussed in an [old version of the Maintenance Agency FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20120616044022/http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166-faqs/iso_3166_faqs_specific.htm):

> You can use `EU` for the name European Union. Please note that this is
>   not an official ISO 3166-1 country code. The European Union is not a
>   country but rather an organization. As such it is not eligible to be
>   formally included in ISO 3166-1. Recognizing, however, that many users
>   of ISO 3166-1 have a practical need to encode that name the ISO
>   3166/MA reserved the two-letter combination `EU` for the purpose of
>   identifying the European Union within the framework of ISO 3166-1.

This document is apparently no longer available, although parts of the statement are widely quoted on other Web sites (e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Criteria_for_inclusion)).